# Is there a difference between a range and an interval?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Can the terms 'interval' and 'range' be used interchangeably or do they describe different things?

I am talking specifically about sets of numbers under a suitable $<$ relation, such that they can be described as $r = [a,b]$, $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$, or $(a,b]$, meaning that for any $a < c < b$, we have $c \in r$ (and $a$ and $b$ depending on the respective brace used).

Comment: Usually [Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)) in math a specific and different meaning. But in the context ["range of values"](https://study.com/academy/lesson/range-of-values-definition-lesson-quiz.html) it means an *interval*.

Comment: In primary school, I was taught that, "the *range* of a list of numbers is just the difference between the largest and smallest values." I guess this is why the term has also been used to mean an *interval*, since an interval is just all numbers between two given values, but the latter is most commonly preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Can be. But convention gives clarity by usage/familiarity.

If $y=f(x),$ then you can consider an interval anywhere in the full extent of domain of independent variable $x$. Range is used for difference of max/min of dependent variable $y.$

Answer (score 0):

Your sets above are called intervals. "Range" is unusual .

Comment: I have seen people say *on the range $(x, y)$* or something along those lines, here and there.

Comment: Fred: Is it also wrong or just unusual?